# Issues while Loading images in ADF, not showing properly

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

When i add images to my home page or Login page, while running first time in the browser its not fetching the images(giving the symbol of broken images) but next time if you log-out and reload, try again, its loading the images.

Dont know what is the issue. Can somebody help with this.?

Comment: Please add more info: example code, project settings, Etc.

Comment: I won't necessary call this an issue, this is a small inconvenience happening during development time. It won't have any effect on your live environment, so you should be fine.

Comment: No, thats the issue.